# Created dotnet app in gcloud cmd, how to download source

Tags: .net, git, download, clone, gcloud

I just cannot figure this out. I am sure it is extremely simple.

I have created a dotnet core application using this tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-aspnetcore/#0

Now, all I want to do, is to get the project from the google server down to my local computer, so I can continue developing on it using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried the same tutorial and stuck with pretty much same issue. After playing around with it a bit, I created a git repo, and pushed the files to remote repository, github in this case, and then from there, I was able to clone into my local computer.